# The Power of Math

Tags: mathematics

If $(M+A+T+H)^4=MATH,$ then what are M, A, T, and H?
See if you can also find it for $(P+O+W+E+R)^5=POWER$ (I don't think that it has a solution) and $(T+H+E)^3=THE$

Comment: Just to clarify, in $MATH$, those are digits in a base-10 number? Or multiplied together?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For MATH:

> Assuming that M, A, T and H are between 0 and 9, we just need to find the 4th powers with 4 digits :
>
>  $6^4 = 1296$  $\Rightarrow$ 1+2+9+6 = 18
>  $7^4 = 2401$  $\Rightarrow$ 2+4+0+1 = 7
>  $8^4 = 4096$  $\Rightarrow$ 4+0+9+6 = 19
>  $9^4 = 6561$  $\Rightarrow$ 6+5+6+1 = 18
>
>  So M = 2, A = 4, T = 0 and H = 1

For POWER:

> We just need to find the 5th powers with 5 digits:
>
>  $7^5 = 16807$  $\Rightarrow$ 1+6+8+0+7 = 22
>  $8^5 = 32768$  $\Rightarrow$ 3+2+7+6+8 = 26
>  $9^5 = 59049$  $\Rightarrow$ 5+9+0+4+9 = 27
>
>  So it's not possible.

For THE:

> We just need to find the cubes with 3 digits:
>
>  $5^3 = 125$  $\Rightarrow$ 1+2+5 = 8
>  $6^3 = 216$  $\Rightarrow$ 2+1+6 = 9
>  $7^3 = 343$  $\Rightarrow$ 3+4+3 = 10
>  $8^3 = 512$  $\Rightarrow$ 5+1+2 = 8
>  $9^3 = 729$  $\Rightarrow$ 7+2+9 = 18
>
>  So T = 5, H = 1 and E = 2

Bonus:

> $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, (0 + 0 + 0 + ... + 0 + 0 + 0)^n = 000...000$

Answer (score 2):

Bonus for OF, as in the power OF math:

> We just need to find squares with 2 digits:
>
>  $4^2 = 16$  $\Rightarrow$ 1+6 = 7
>  $5^2 = 25$  $\Rightarrow$ 2+5 = 7
>  $6^2 = 36$  $\Rightarrow$ 3+6 = 9
>  $7^2 = 49$  $\Rightarrow$ 4+9 = 13
>  $8^2 = 64$  $\Rightarrow$ 6+4 = 10
>  $9^2 = 81$  $\Rightarrow$ 8+1 = 9
>
>  So O = 8 and F = 1.

Comment: [Of Alley](https://knowyourlondon.wordpress.com/2016/04/01/of-alley/) used to be a London street in an area once owned by "George Villiers, Duke Of Buckingham" and each street took part of his name